# Google Sheets API node.js quickstart won't work: The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I've been messing with the Google Sheets API for a project and everything has been going pretty well. I followed all the steps [On this page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs) and got the quickstart working great for a while... Until I ran into an issue where I was getting the error message `API returned an error: Error: The request does not have valid authentication credentials.`

To resolve this I tried a bunch of different things from changing the SCOPES variable to commenting and uncommenting out things.

Eventually I deleted the project and credentials on my google developers console account and tried to make a new one.

Whenever I start a new folder from scratch, make a quickstart.js file, install the node modules and run it, now I get `The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client`. I've made completely new client_secret.json files and made the quickstart.js from scratch directly using the quickstart walkthrough code and it won't work. What could be causing this?

[Link to github (this is the code that WAS mostly working until I tried to delete rows from my google sheet after copying data to my sql database).](https://github.com/R-Dubz/DaycareScheduler/tree/master/Sheets%20API%20Quickstart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try what was done in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201949/node-js-with-gmail-api-the-api-returned-an-error-error-unauthorized-client) wherein this hidden file has been deleted:

```
/Users/user/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json
```

In your case, you need to locate the path of `sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json` then delete.

For this, you might need to also do a console.log to locate the correct path.

Comment: Thank you! Marked this as the answer. I found the file, deleted it, and then did my thing and we're on the right track again :). I feel really stupid. The code in the quickstart says:
`// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json`
and I had no idea where ~/.credentials was until you put the Users/user there :(. Made so much more sense after that. Thank you!