# Node.js in google drive update image: Error: unauthorized_client

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

During this execution of this method:

```
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      console.log(TOKEN_PATH);
      console.log(token);
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}
```

I receive this error:

> token.json Buffer 7b 22 61 63 63 65 73 73 5f 74 6f 6b 65 6e 22 3a...
>   The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client { Error:
>   unauthorized_client

The file `crendential.json` was download directly from my drive with an user that can create folder in drive.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After a google search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201949/node-js-with-gmail-api-the-api-returned-an-error-error-unauthorized-client). If that didn't help, can you tell us your OS and the result of `console.log(TOKEN_PATH)`?

### Edit:

Lets say `TOKEN = 123456` and `TOKEN` is located in `Users/dadojar/Documents/test`.

`console.log(TOKEN_PATH)` Should print `Users/dadojar/Documents/test`

`console.log(TOKEN)` should print `123456`.

From my understanding of your comments, `console.log(TOKEN_PATH)` prints `123456` (which it should not).

Comment: PS: I would normally ask this in a comment, but for some reason SE doesn't want me to post links in comments today, and all my `<a href="#">this</a>` result in the entire url showing up in the comment

Comment: TOKEN_PATH return me the token.json, that is placed in the root of the project...

Comment: It doesn't return the *path* of the token?  That is probably the problem.

Comment: It return the token.json that is in the root project. It works properly. Consider that I create a const "const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';"

Answer (score 0):

I solve with this code:

```
 var jwToken = new google.auth.JWT(   key.client_email,   null,   key.private_key, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],   null ); jwToken.authorize((authErr) => {   if (authErr) {
        console.log("error : " + authErr);
        return;   } else {
        console.log("Auth OK");   } });
```